# How do I handle exceptions correctly in this case?

Tags: java, file-io, exception, error-handling

I have a class called Dictionary which reads constant-length-delimited words from a text file and creates a TreeSet from them for looking up whether or not a word exists in the dictionary.

So I obviously need to handle an IOException somehow. My question is, should the error-handling responsibilities fall upon the Dictionary class, or should it fall upon the code creating a Dictionary object?

Here's what I have:

```
public class Dictionary
{
    private final TreeSet<String> stringSet = new TreeSet<>();

    // constructor
    public Dictionary(String fileName) throws IOException
    {
        try (final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName)))
        {
            // load dictionary into stringSet
            final char[] buffer = new char[4];
            int numRead = -1;
            while ((numRead = reader.read(buffer)) > 0)
                stringSet.add(new String(buffer, 0, numRead).toUpperCase());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public boolean contains(String word)
    {
        return stringSet.contains(word);
    }
}
```

And the code that creates a Dictionary object:

```
public class MainClass
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String fileName = "C:/Users/Brandon/Desktop/Android Development/Practice Apps/SwapWords_Prototype/src/data/dictionary.txt";
        try
        {
            Dictionary dict = new Dictionary(fileName);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Could not load dictionary <" + fileName + ">");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // TODO handle dict
    }
}
```

Should Dictionary catch and handle the IOException or throw it to the calling code? I mean, either one works, but which is more logical?

Comment: What you've done looks ok (catch exceptions as late as you can) except that you can get rid of `catch (IOException e) { throw e; }`…

Comment: I would move the logic of loading a dictionary file to its own separate method (to be used something like `new Dictionary().load(File)`). Then remove the throws from the constructor. On a side note, this question is a better fit for [CodeReview StackExchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Perception: Thanks so much for this idea. It actually solved a problem that I was going to have to write ass-backward code to get around. It's much more organized and it's much more obvious what's being done. Also thanks for the CodeReview link, I didn't even know it existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that the way you have it set up right now is good as is. If it is the case that when `Dictionary` encounters an `IOException`, there isn't any good way for it to recover, then you will want to alert the caller that this failure occurred. If, on the other hand, `Dictionary` could gracefully handle the error on its own (by trying to load a different file or something), then you could put the code in the constructor to hide it from the caller.

What you don't want is for the caller to make a `Dictionary` that is internally invalid due to an exception, but looks completely fine to the caller.

Comment: I feel stupid for having to ask this, but...with the code I have now, any references to `dict` after the catch-try block in `MainClass` _cannot be resolved_. I'm confused.

Comment: Yes. Because `dict` is declared inside the `try` block, it is local to that block of code. If you want to be able to use it outside, you will need to declare it outside (and simply initialize it inside). Alternatively, just put all of your code that requires `dict` INSIDE the try block, since if we hit the `catch` block, then `dict` isn't valid anyways, so we probably don't want to be using it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your comment until now: I didn't get a notification about your edit, where you actually asked your question.